# Change of variables - Black-Scholes

Tags: option-pricing, black-scholes

While manipulating the Black-Scholes equation, Paul Wilmott (Paul Wilmott on Quantitative Finance, chapter 7, page 110) makes the following change of variables and I am having trouble understanding how he evaluated the second derivative:

[image]

Comment: Do you understand how the first derivative was calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not own the book you're referring to. However, we know that the payoff of an option has the following representation in order to satisfy the Black-Scholes PDE (this is a consequence of the [Feynman-Kac formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%E2%80%93Kac_formula)):

$$V(S,t)= e^{-r(T-t)}\cdot U(S,t) = X \cdot U(S,t),$$

where $X = e^{-r(T-t)}$ for convenience. Now, using a change of variable, $\xi = log(S)$, the above equation becomes:

$$ V(\xi,t)= X \cdot U(\xi,t)$$

and therefore we get the following derivatives by applying the chain-rule and the quotation-rule (under the second-order derivative):

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial V}{\partial S} &= X \cdot \frac{\partial U}{\partial \xi} \cdot \frac{\partial \xi}{\partial S} \\
&= X \cdot \frac{\partial U}{\partial \xi} \frac{1}{S} \\
&= X \cdot e^{-\xi} \cdot \frac{\partial U}{\partial \xi}\\
\end{align}
where $S=e^{\xi}$ from the change of variable. Moreover, we get:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2V}{\partial S^2} &=  \frac{\partial}{\partial S} \left[X \cdot \frac{\partial U}{\partial \xi} \frac{1}{S}\right]\\
&= X \cdot \frac{\partial U}{\partial \xi} \cdot \frac{-1}{S^2} + X \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial S} \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial \xi}\right) \cdot \frac{1}{S}\\
&= X \cdot \frac{\partial U}{\partial \xi} \cdot \frac{-1}{S^2} + X \cdot \frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial \xi^2} \cdot \frac{\partial \xi}{\partial S} \cdot \frac{1}{S}\\
&= X \cdot \frac{\partial U}{\partial \xi} \cdot \frac{-1}{S^2} + X \cdot \frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial \xi^2} \cdot \frac{1}{S^2}\\
&=-X\cdot e^{-2\xi} \cdot \frac{\partial U}{\partial \xi} + X \cdot e^{-2\xi} \cdot \frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial \xi^2}.
\end{align}
Now, under the Black-Scholes PDE all of the terms have common factor $X$ and thus you can conveniently divide out the common factor. I believe, that is why $X$ is not included in your above specified derivations, since it does not contribute to the overall solution of the PDE.